# Angular 2: router.navigate not working under if condition

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

Angular 2: I want to redirect to "inventory" component based on if condition. While doing router.navigate to "inventory" component, it gets redirected to default component i.e. dashboard
But i tried redirecting to external [url](https://stackoverflow.com) instead which is working. So logic is correct. Below is the code:

```
if(!(isStockManager()))
{
    this.router.navigate(['/inventory']);
    //document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}
else if(!(isWaiter()))
{
    this.router.navigate(['/waiter']);
}
else{
     this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
}
```

Here is my pages.routing:

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}},
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}},
  { path: 'waiter', redirectTo: 'waiter/table-list',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}},
  { path: 'waiter', loadChildren: './waiter/waiter.module#WaiterModule',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}},
  { path: 'inventory', loadChildren: './inventory/inventory.module#InventoryModule',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}},
  { path: 'inventory', redirectTo: 'inventory/inventory',resolve: {data: LoginResolveService}}
```

Comment: Have you checked that conditions you are trying is getting fulfilled? And the way you defined component for routing?

Comment: Please show the router entries of your app.module

Comment: i edited my question @TheDictator

Comment: why do you have a redirect and a loadchildren for the same path?